# Postgres does not work with django eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, postgresql

I installed django and installed the pydev plugin under eclipse. Then I downloaded the postgres(1.16.0) sql tool and installed that. Here are my settings:

[image]

Then I wanted to configure the setting file under django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' , 
        'NAME': 'django',                   
        'USER': 'postgres',                 
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',                
        'HOST': '',        
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
}
```

but when I do syncdb i get:

```
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\creation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2.extensions
ImportError: No module named psycopg2.extensions
```

What do I do wrong?

PS.: I am developing under win7 and eclipse juno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [psycopg2](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/)

```
pip install psycopg2
```

> Psycopg is the most popular PostgreSQL adapter for the Python programming language. At its core it fully implements the Python DB API 2.0 specifications.